# Symfony2 create symbolic link to custom resources

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, assets

On symfony2 install or update, there are symbolic links created for different bundles on web folder inside bundles folder.

I want to do same on symfony2 install/update command to create more symbolic links for different resources, there path is outside the bundles.

How can I do that without writing class or functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's composer feature to execute scripts on some events. You might have a look to [this article](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md).

Example:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "script.sh --param=value"
    ],
  }
}
```